# Preferred Way of Creating Singleton in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, singleton

I'm creating a relatively straightforward "bag-o-functions".

In JS, whenever I want to access local helper methods that are too generic to expose, I generally do the following:

```
Util = new function () {
    var helper = function () {}
    this.myPublic = function () {
        // some code that uses the helper
    }
}
```

Is this an acceptable way to achieve the same in CoffeeScript?

```
@Util = class
  helper = ->
  @myPublic = ->
    # some code that uses the helper
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
Util = new (->
  helper = ->
  @myPublic = ->
    # some code that uses the helper
    return
  return
)
```